# String split with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a log file what contains S.M.A.R.T. data of my hard drive.
I would like to handle this file with PowerShell. 
Here is the part of my log file.

```
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0020   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

And here is my code

```
$i = 1
$a = Get-Content log.txt

do {
$trimmed = $a[$i].trim()
$splitted = $trimmed.split(" ")
$i++
}while ($i -le 3)
```

If I use the .split(" ") it is working only with the thrid row.
How can I split my all rows correctly?

Thank you

Comment: if I put
    $splitted[2]
before the end of the loop I can not get the expected values.( 0x0020 0x0030 0x0032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does this do for you?

```
$a = Get-Content log.txt    
-split $a
```

I get this

```
H:\> -split $a
3
Spin_Up_Time
0x0020
100
100
000
Old_age
Offline
-
0
4
Start_Stop_Count
0x0030
100
100
000
Old_age
Offline
-
0
5
Reallocated_Sector_Ct
0x0032
100
100
000
Old_age
Always
-
0
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more code, but it gives you something that's a little easier to work with in the end:

```
$SMART = gc c:\temp\test.txt | %{
    $temp = $_ -split " "|?{!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))}
    new-object psobject -Property @{
        "Entry"=$temp[0]
        "TestName"=$temp[1]
        "HexCode"=$temp[2]
        "Number1"=$temp[3]
        "Number2"=$temp[4]
        "Number3"=$temp[5]
        "Age"=$temp[6]
        "Status"=$temp[7]
        "Filler"=$temp[8]
        "Zero?"=$temp[9]
    }
}
$SMART|FT Entry,TestName,HexCode,Number1,Number2,Number3,Age,Status,Filler,Zero?
```

Answer (score 0):

I like working with regex' here's a sample that allows you to name your columns.

```
$a = Get-Content log.txt
$pattern = [regex]'(?<rowid>\d+)\s(?<desc>[a-zA-Z_]+)\s+(?<hexdata>0x\d{4})\s+(?<col4>\d{3})\s+(?<col5>\d{3})\s+(?<col6>\d{3})\s+(?<text1>.+?)\s+(?<state>.+?)-\s+0'

foreach ($line in $a) {
    if ($line -match $pattern) {
        $dataobj = New-Object PSObject
        $dataobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $matches['desc']
        $dataobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Hex Data" -value $matches['hexdata']
        $dataobj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "State" -value $matches['state']

        $dataobj
    }

}
```

Results:

```
Description                                          Hex Data                                             State                                              
-----------                                          --------                                             -----                                              
Spin_Up_Time                                         0x0020                                               Offline                                            
Start_Stop_Count                                     0x0030                                               Offline                                            
Reallocated_Sector_Ct                                0x0032                                               Always
```